# Inserting a UTF-8 NSString in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, utf-8

I have an Objective-C NSString (say, 'Gabriel García Márquez') that I want to pass to PHP via a POST request, which in turn will call a MySQL insert to add the string to a utf8-bin column. Trouble is, the string does some shapeshifting along the way, and I've read every Stack Overflow post on the subject to prevent it.

The POST request (with charset UTF-8) contains 'Gabriel Garc\U00eda M\U00e1rquez'.

If I insert that string into a utf8-bin column right away without an encode or decode, the result in MySQL is '4761627269656c2047617263c3ad614dc3a1727175657a'. If I wrap the string in utf8_decode(), the result is 'Gabriel Garc'. If I wrap the string in utf8_encode() (hey, why not?), the result is the same as the first string.

What am I missing to prevent this text from devolving into garbage?

Some notes to make this all the more frustrating:

- I call mysql_set_charset('UTF8', $conn) before the insert query.
- The table is collated in utf8_bin, the columns are utf8_bin.

Comment: Maybe a dumb comment, but have you utf8 encoded it in objective-c before passing it to php?

Comment: I am using ASIHTTPRequest, which I've set to encode any POST strings I give it to UTF-8. Or so I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops...it's a phpMyAdmin bug. '4761627269656c2047617263c3ad614dc3a1727175657a' is, surprisingly, correct in a different environment -- it prints readably in, say, MySQL Workbench. Only took me two days to figure that out...